# Deleted Linux partitions but still get grub error and cannot boot into windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, grub

I had Windows 7 and Linux on a RAID0 disk- I deleted Linux, now when I boot I cannot get into Windows 7. I just get a grub error.

If I try and use the Grub Repair tool and put that on a USB stick to boot from, it says "BOOTMGR is missing"

If I boot the Win 7 CD and then go to do a repair it says "This version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the version of Windows you are trying to repair"- although it is the same :s

How can I remove grub to boot windows normally??

Comment: GPT or MBR based disk/system?

Comment: "... although it is the same" - Are you sure? Check whether you have a Win7 DVD and had Win7 SP1 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and was able to solve it by booting into the Windows recovery CD and running the following commands from a command prompt.

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

I previously [wrote a more detailed blog post](http://www.asiel.us/wordpress/2011/04/13/fixing-windows-7-mbr/) about what worked for me as well.